# ZK Can we Save Windows Component State?

Tags: java, zk

Let us suppose I have a zul page in which I have different component like textbox,intbox,buttons etc ... now i drag and drop component here and there now i want to save the state of Window and when again i will come to same page same position of all component will show..How to do it in ZK Framework.Here is demo code

```
<zk xmlns:x="xhtml" xmlns:zk="zk">
    <window width="100%" height="100%">
        <borderlayout width="100%" height="100%">
            <north border="none">
                <menubar sclass="vista" height="20px">
                    <menuitem label="ADD" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="Delete" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="Refresh" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />

                    <menuitem label="Add t0 links" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />

                    <menu label="View">
                        <menupopup>
                            <menuitem label="View details"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Edit View"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label=" Summery View"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>

                    <menuitem label="Edit" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                </menubar>
            </north>
            <center border="none" sclass="sub-tab-panel">
                <groupbox vflex="1" hflex="1"
                    contentStyle="overflow:auto" width="880px">
                    <separator width="25px" />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption label="Grid Demo"
                            sclass="group-header" />
                        <grid>
                            <rows>
                                <row>
                                    <label value="Mike" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="29" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="C" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                </row>
                                <row>
                                    <label value="Todd" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="21" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="B" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                </row>
                                <row>
                                    <label value="Tony" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="31" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                    <label value="A" draggable="row"
                                        droppable="row" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                                </row>
                            </rows>
                        </grid>
                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption
                            label="13 000001 000 00 BP Building Permit"
                            sclass="group-header" />

                        <vlayout width="100%">
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Type"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label
                                            value="BP Building Permit" maxlength="30"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Status"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Application"
                                            maxlength="30" sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Sub Type"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Residential"
                                            maxlength="30" sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Parent ID"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="1212"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Work"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Demo"
                                            sclass="field-data" maxlength="30" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Row ID"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="12"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Group"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Permit"
                                            sclass="field-data" maxlength="30" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>

                            </hlayout>
                        </vlayout>

                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption label="DEMO" sclass="group-header" />

                        <vlayout width="100%">
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Type"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label
                                            value="BP Building Permit" maxlength="30"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Status"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Application"
                                            maxlength="30" sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Sub Type"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Residential"
                                            maxlength="30" sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Parent ID"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="1212"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Work"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Demo"
                                            sclass="field-data" maxlength="30" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Row ID"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="12"
                                            sclass="field-data" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>
                            </hlayout>
                            <hlayout width="100%">
                                <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                    onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                    <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                        <label value="Group"
                                            sclass="field-label" />
                                    </hbox>
                                    <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                        <label value="Permit"
                                            sclass="field-data" maxlength="30" />
                                    </hbox>
                                </hbox>

                            </hlayout>
                        </vlayout>

                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption label="Primary Property"
                            sclass="group-header" />
                        <hlayout width="100%" draggable="h_td1"
                            droppable="h_td1" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                            <hbox draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                                <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                    <label value="Address"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </hbox>
                                <hbox align="left" width="292px">
                                    <label
                                        value="23 NW #1 SAMMIE'S LAND OF DREA..." maxlength="30"
                                        sclass="field-data" />
                                </hbox>
                            </hbox>

                        </hlayout>
                        <hlayout draggable="h_td" droppable="h_td"
                            onDrop="move(event.dragged)" width="792px">
                            <hbox width="92px" pack="end">
                                <label value="Address"
                                    sclass="field-label" />
                            </hbox>
                            <hbox align="left" width="692px">
                                <textbox rows="2" draggable="false"
                                    style="resize:none" value="" readonly="true"
                                    sclass="field-data" width="692px" />
                            </hbox>
                        </hlayout>

                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption
                            label="Tracking Dates and Reference Information"
                            sclass="group-header" />
                        <x:table width="100%" border="0"
                            cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px">
                            <x:tr height="20px">
                                <x:td width="77px" align="right">
                                    <label value="In Date"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td width="150px">
                                    <label value="2013-11-07"
                                        sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Issue/Approve"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td width="150px">
                                    <label id="issueDate" value=""
                                        sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Expires"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td width="150px">
                                    <label value="" sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                            </x:tr>
                            <x:tr height="20px">
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Ref. No."
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td>
                                    <label value="" sclass="field-data"
                                        maxlength="20" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Issued By"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td>
                                    <label value="" sclass="field-data"
                                        maxlength="15" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Final Date"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td>
                                    <label value="" sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                            </x:tr>
                            <x:tr height="20px">
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Name"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td colspan="3">
                                    <label value="" maxlength="50"
                                        sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td align="right">
                                    <label value="Priority"
                                        sclass="field-label" />
                                </x:td>
                                <x:td>
                                    <label value="" sclass="field-data" />
                                </x:td>
                            </x:tr>
                        </x:table>
                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px"
                        style="resize:none" draggable="grpbox" droppable="grpbox"
                        onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption label="Description"
                            sclass="group-header">
                        </caption>
                        <hlayout>
                            <textbox rows="3" hflex="1" readonly="true"
                                style="resize:none"
                                value="Update through Jooq Test Case on: Thu Nov 14 17:13:51 IST 2013"
                                sclass="field-data" />
                        </hlayout>
                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />
                    <groupbox mold="3d" width="770px" draggable="grpbox"
                        droppable="grpbox" onDrop="move(event.dragged)">
                        <caption label="Conditions"
                            sclass="group-header" />
                        <hlayout>
                            <textbox rows="3" hflex="1" readonly="true"
                                style="resize:none" value="" sclass="field-data" />
                        </hlayout>
                    </groupbox>
                    <separator />

                </groupbox>
            </center>
            <south border="0">
                <menubar id="buttonBar" width="100%" height="20px">
                    <menuitem label="Audit" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menu label="Copy">
                        <menupopup>
                            <menuitem label="Single Copy"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Multiple Properties"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>

                    <menuitem label="Create Child" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="Create Violation"
                        draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                        onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="Revise" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem id="issueMenu" label="Issue/Approve"
                        draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                        onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menu label="Print">
                        <menupopup>
                            <menuitem label="Print" draggable="topmenu"
                                droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Inspection Card"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Label" draggable="topmenu"
                                droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Inspection Report"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuseparator></menuseparator>
                            <menuitem label="Custom Report 1"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Custom Report 2"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Custom Report 3"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>
                    <menu label="Email">
                        <menupopup>
                            <menuitem label="Print Output"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="File" draggable="topmenu"
                                droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Document on this Folder"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                            <menuitem label="Attachment on this Folder"
                                draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                                onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                        </menupopup>
                    </menu>
                    <menuitem label="Re-Default" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="GIS" draggable="topmenu"
                        droppable="topmenu" onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                    <menuitem label="Process Activity"
                        draggable="topmenu" droppable="topmenu"
                        onDrop="move(event.dragged)" />
                </menubar>
            </south>
        </borderlayout>
        <zscript><![CDATA[
    void move(Component dragged) {
        self.parent.insertBefore(dragged, self);
        //if (self instanceof Hlayout) {
        //self.parent.insertBefore(dragged, self);
        //} else {
        //  self.appendChild(dragged);
        //}
    }
]]></zscript>
    </window>
</zk>
```

Now How to save news state of window?

Answer (score 2):

All components are serializable (`java.io.Serializable`). Like cloning, all children and descendants are serialized. If you serialize a component and then de-serialize it back, the result will be the same as invoking Component.clone()
 save the component when ever you want to redraw the same state of component call `isInvalidated()` of the component.

isInvalidated

boolean `isInvalidated()`
Returns if this component needs to be redrawn at the client.
Application developers rarely need to call this method.

Note:

It always returns true if it doesn't belong to any page (since redraw is required if it is attached to a page later).
It always returns true if the current execution is not an asynchronous update (so redrawn is always required).
If its parent is **invalidated**, this component will be redrawn too, but this method returns false if `invalidate()` was not called against this component.

Comment: Here is one Question As you can check in my example Everything in ZUL and component are not part of Java Code if i will save the clone of Window and invalidate it again load the save state will it effect zul? becuase zul content all components